# http ajax call inside Google Extension

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, http, google-chrome-extension

I have a simple google extension that calls a Web API with **HTTP** Url

In the `customscript.js` file, I have the below ajax call

```
function Getresponse()
{
   return $.ajax({
       url: "http://url",
       crossDomain: true,
       async: false,
       success: callback
    });
}
```

**I have now two behaviors,**

1. When open **HTTP** page then click on the google extension icon, it is working properly and I get the response from the API without any issue.
2. When open **HTTPs** page then clicks on the google extension icon, it's not working by any means.

I traced the issue and made sure that this is **because of** the API URL is HTTP, not HTTPS

**My question is** How can call HTTP API in google extension whatever the current page is HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: Make the AJAX call from the background script, not the content script.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment, the extension working properly with HTTP pages, Is this suggestion will solve the issue with HTTPS pages?

Comment: I tried to call the HTTP ajax call in the background that gives me a mixed content error!

Comment: There are many ways to do it incorrectly so it'd be helpful if you add your new manifest.json with the background page declaration and background script code.